# Prevent drop shadow from effecting different layers in Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In the image below, my drop shadow is applied to layer 7, yet it is impacting layer 8.  I don't want the drop shadow to appear on the right edge of the layer.  I only want the circle to have a drop shadow.  I've turned off global light.

[image]

Comment: How did you apply the drop shadow? Can you show the effects not only of Layer 7, but on Layer 8 as well?

Comment: Your Layer 7 has a tall strip of pixels on the right side, which are just outside the canvas (not visible), but still cast the shadow. You should delete that strip (to make its shadow disappear).

Or just move Layer 7 with a Move tool, to see what is going on.

Comment: @IvanKuckir  You just blew my mind.  Yes!  That was it.  Thanks very much indeed!

Comment: @IvanKuckir a perfect answer. Why not post it as one? I would vote it up, and that would give you reputation points. :)

Comment: @LPChip I wrote it as an answer :) But I am still not sure it will ever be useful to anybody, because the title of the question is quite misleading.

Comment: @IvanKuckir that's not the only reason to write an answer. The second reason is, so it can be accepted and we all know  OP no longer needs help. Otherwise people keep coming back to a question that already was answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Layer 7 has a tall strip of pixels on the right side, which are just outside the canvas (not visible), but still cast the shadow. You should delete that strip (to make its shadow disappear).

Or just move Layer 7 with a Move tool, to see what is going on.

Comment: +1 as promised. If you hadn't already answered it in the comments, I would've posted this as an answer. :)